# How can I return values from a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I have my code which does a quick sort on a list of values:

```
def Quick_sort_random(random_list):
    r = random_list.copy()
    def inner(r):
        if len(r) < 2:
            return r
        p = random.randint(0, len(r) - 1)
        pivot = r[p]
        left = list(filter(lambda x: x <= pivot, r[:p] + r[p + 1:]))
        right = list(filter(lambda x: x > pivot, r[:p] + r[p + 1:]))
        return Quick_sort_random(left) + [pivot] + Quick_sort_random(right)
    a = inner(r)
    return random_list,a
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

I have the inner() function because I want to return both the original list and the sorted list. How can I fix this?

Comment: the general recipe is that _either_ you use a argument in function signature to act as your "running tally" (or list, or dictionary, or whatever aggregate data structure you need), with a default value for the first invocation, or you return "something + recursionResult".

Comment: You have `Quick_sort_random` return two values (which is a tuple), but then you only want one of those two values when you make the recursive call.  You could either write `Quick_sort_random(left)[1]` (and likewise for the right) to get just the second value.  Or clearer might be `_, sorted_left = Quick_sort_random(left)` and then use `sorted_left` and `sorted_right` in the concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Quick_sort_random` function returns a tuple but you only need the second item in it for the sorting. Change the last line in `inner` to:

```
return Quick_sort_random(left)[1] + [pivot] + Quick_sort_random(right)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the sorted list in `inner` function:

```py
import random

def Quick_sort_random(random_list):
    r = random_list.copy()
    def inner(r):
        if len(r) < 2:
            return r
        p = random.randint(0, len(r) - 1)
        pivot = r[p]
        left = list(filter(lambda x: x <= pivot, r[:p] + r[p + 1:]))
        right = list(filter(lambda x: x > pivot, r[:p] + r[p + 1:]))
        unsorted_left, sorted_left = Quick_sort_random(left)
        unsorted_right, sorted_right = Quick_sort_random(right)
        return sorted_left + [pivot] + sorted_right
    a = inner(r)
    return random_list,a 

print(Quick_sort_random([4,5,1,5,2,3]))
```

**Output:**

```py
([4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])
```